# SSRS pulling the parameter from multiple location

Tags: reporting-services, parameters

I need to know if there is a way for us to display a single parameter report by pulling the same parameter from multiple drop down controls.

Does SSRS allow us to have multiple controls(drop down ) to pull the same parameter from different set of data.

Comment: I reread this three times and don't understand what you mean.  Please reword or give an example or a screen shot of what you are after - it makes no sense whatsoever.

Comment: There is a input parameter called Lot Number, I want to display 1. Incmplete lots in one drop down control 2. Completed in one 3. I would also need the user to input the lot # in a text box.  The parameter is same but user needs a different ways to input the same parameter. Does it make sense?

Comment: that doesn't help at all sorry I cannot help you with this sort of details.  Read it yourself and pretend you are an outsider and see if you yourself could answer such a question.

Comment: There is a input parameter called Lot Number, I want to display 1. Incmplete lots in one drop down control 2. Completed in one 3. I would also need the user to input the lot # in a text box.  The parameter is same but user needs a different ways to input the same parameter. Does it make sense?

Comment: So create a shared data set for 1 and 2.  And three parameters in total, I don't see the difficulty in this but then again I don't understand the question being asked.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a server that can access the locations of the first two sets of data, then the easiest way to be for those would be to combine them into one with a **UNION** and use a single parameter for them.

I'm guessing that may not be possible so you can create a separate dataset and parameter for it.

Then create another parameter for your entered value. Allow these parameters to have a NULL value so that they do not **have** to be selected.

Create WHERE clause logic in your SQL to deal with the parameters for the LOT_NUMBER:

```
WHERE LOT_NUMBER IN (@INCOMPLETE) 
   OR LOT_NUMBER IN (@COMPLETE) 
   OR LOT_NUMBER IN (@ENTERED)
```

This will allow uses to choose from the first or second drop downs or enter a third value. The downside is that the user can potentially use all three at the same time.

Comment: thanks! This is what exactly I was asking, I will see what I can do to avoid user from selecting the value from more than one filter.